# The ls command is returning nothing when ran in root, why?

Tags: terminal

when I preform sudo su and become the root user I do a cd then I'm at

root@brandon-NV57H:~#

When I try the ls command nothing is returned but root@brandon-NV57H:~#

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps there is nothing in root's home directory. what does `ls -al` return? How about `pwd`?

Comment: ls -al returned something and pwd returned /root

Comment: This question isn't about programming, you should search/ask in in Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no files in ~root, which is /root